# Background color for HTML page generating QR code

Tags: php, html

I've below PHP code which shows QR code & I'm showing it in center on submitting password. Now, since I'm keeping it in center, the rest of the page appears white & I want entire browser background color to be in blue. I tried putting bgcolor but that only changes the middle section's background where image appears & I need entire browser's background color to be blue

Here is my code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}

                html, body {
                    height: 100%;
                }

                html {
                    display: table;
                    margin: auto;
                }

                body {
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                // reading from post
            }
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                    <table width="380px">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">Password:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"><span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
        </form>

        <?php
                    if ($password) {

                    echo "<img src='./myqrcode.php?password=$password' />";

                ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can any one tell me how to put blue color as background?

Thanks

Comment: You tried something like this : `background-color: blue;` to the `body` element and it still didn't work? Just make sure that there aren't any default margins or paddings for the `body` element.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the background in the body? Can you show us a screenshot?

You can try

```
    body {
                vertical-align: middle;
                background-color: blue;
            }
```

By the way, it's a bad idea to use tables for designing the layout of the page. Use divs instead. Like here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

And also don't use old-fashioned html tags like "bgcolor", use only CSS for styling.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="backgroundoclor:blue;">
    <?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            // reading from post
        }
    ?>
```